# How to store a trained classifier?

Tags: python, django, scipy, nlp, scikit-learn

A classifier is trained to predict the news category when a URL is fed into it

**Currently** : For every input, I train the classifier and then return the output and hence i lose the trained classifier

**Expected** : Once i train the classifier,I should be able to call this classifier from memory whenever needed

Any light onto this would be highly appreciated.
**PS:amateur in NLP**

Answer (score 1):

is [that](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html) what you want?

example from [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html):

```
>>> from sklearn import svm
>>> from sklearn import datasets
>>> clf = svm.SVC()
>>> iris = datasets.load_iris()
>>> X, y = iris.data, iris.target
>>> clf.fit(X, y)  
SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
    decision_function_shape=None, degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='rbf',
    max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
    tol=0.001, verbose=False)

>>> import pickle
>>> s = pickle.dumps(clf)    # <-- save/dump classifier to disk
>>> clf2 = pickle.loads(s)   # <-- read/load saved classifier from disk to a new variable
>>> clf2.predict(X[0:1])     # <-- use loaded (from disk) classifier
array([0])
>>> y[0]
0
```

Comment: are you suggesting i use sklearn instead of nlp ?

Comment: try to to pickle your `nip` classifier object - most probably it'll work...

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Pickle** / **cPickle** to dump/load your model.

```
import pickle

#Some COde
model_path = "classifier.model"
if not os.path.exists(model_path):
    #Some Code
    classifier = # Some Classifer
    pickle.dump(classifier, open(model_path, "wb" ))
else:
    classifier = pickle.load(open(model_path, "rb"))

#Some Code
```

For more information : [Pickle / cPickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html)